# use NPAPI plugin with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npapi

I am making a node app which utilizes a npapi plugin. basically I am trying to make it so if the device or browser that connects to the server does not support the plugin it will fall back to the server. currently I have a work around like that works however it requires opening a new window on the host computer whenever a request is sent

(workaround route)

```
var open = require('open');
var jobs = [];
router.get('/nsjob', function(req, res, next){
    var job = {
            id:(jobs.length > 0) ? jobs[jobs.length - 1].index + 1:0,
            xml://xml,
            params://params,
            callback:function(err, data){
                if(err)
                  return next(err);
                res.send(data);
            }
        };
    open('http://localhost:3000/handleJob/' + job.index);
});
router.get('/handleJob/:id', function(req, res){
    var job;
    for(var i in jobs){
        if(jobs[i].index === req.params.id){
            job = jobs[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    res.render('hjob', job')
});
router.post('/completedJob/:id', function(req, res){
    var job;
    for(var i in jobs){
        if(jobs[i].index === req.params.id){
            job = jobs[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if(req.body)
       job.callback(req.body.err, req.body.data);
    else
       job.callback(null, null);
    res.end();
});
```

this works all well and good but seems like a very bad way to go about it however I need this fallback option but it makes it almost impossible to use the host computer while mobile devices are running on the server. if I could load NPAPI plugins to node I could modify the api to not use dom and essentially avoid opening a window on the host computer. however I cannot find a way to do this in node NOT NODE-WEBKIT (until it can be shipped to mobile it is pretty much useless in this case as this is primarily used by mobile users.

Answer (score 0):

You could hypothetically write a Node module which would load an NPAPI plugin, but it would be very difficult. There is definitely not any turnkey solution for this.

[FireBreath 2.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebreath-dev/qfcowZkfPz0) will support a new protocol that could probably be used to do this, but it's still in early planning stages.  I don't expect any releases for at least a month or two.

Comment: I have been looking onto this however I cannot find much information on handling npapi plugins I have made a couple node-webkit apps which are made to run transparent. Its not clean but it works however I would like to find a more reliable solution

Comment: you won't find much information either.  It's not something widely done; I'd say there are less than 10 people in the world (certainly less than 20) with the experience with NPAPI to do it without a huge amount of hassle, and none of us particularly want to do it.

that should tell you something.  What you want to do is not a good idea, and I don't recommend you try it.  Find a better solution.

Comment: not only that its about to be phased out which is why I would like to package a solution... at least until the new driver comes out

Comment: Well, NPAPI is being phased out on Chrome. Nobody else has announced plans to get rid of it